# java. I having to reversing my output(palindrome) then declaring if its a palindrome(the same if you reverse it) or not

Tags: java

java. I having to reversing my output(palindrome) then declaring if its a palindrome(the same if you reverse it) or not. Here is my code im not asking for an answer just guidance i have no idea what im doing wrong here. My problem is trying to get my out to reverse.

```
String org, reverse = ""; 
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter the number: ");
org = myScanner.nextLine();
int length = org.length();
int reversenum =0;
int num=0;
System.out.println("The number entered is: " + org);
while( num != 0 ){
    length = reversenum * 10;
    length = reversenum + num%10;
    num = num/10;
}
System.out.println("Reverse of input number is: "+num); /* heres where my 
problem is i think 
for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )reverse = reverse + org.charAt(i);
if (org.equals(reverse)) System.out.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
else System.out.println("Entered string isn't a palindrome.");
}}
```

Comment: you never enter the `while( num != 0 )` since you set `int num=0;`

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Convert the String org to an int, store it in num.

Comment: And don't use another int length. reversenum is enough.

Comment: You loop runs while your varibale `num` is not 0, since it is 0, it skips the loop

Comment: im still confused im sorry everyone

Comment: If you set `int num=0;` then `num` holds `0` as value. Few lines after that you have `while( num != 0 ){...}` but that loops iterates only if condition is `true`. When we test `num != 0` with `num` which holds `0` we end up with test `0 != 0` which is `false`. So you essentially have `while(false){...}` which means it will never iterate (not even once).

Comment: so do i change the 0 with a " "

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't need the while loop at all. If you're checking if the string is a palindrome the for loop and if statements should suffice. And then you could just print out reverse after the loop.